# Selenium Click a Button Without ClassName/ID

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, automation

I am developing a Browser Automation, but I can't click a button. I have tried this procedure:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='uploadForm: fileup']/div[1]/button[1]")).Click();
webDriver.ElementBul(By.("Dosya Yükle"), gecisScreen).Click();
```

HTML

```
<a type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-upload" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n"></span><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Dosya Yükle</span>
</a>
```

As follows:

[image: see Image]

Comment: Show exception log. Also this seem to be public page, can you share exact `URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (IWebElement item in webDriver.ElementleriBul(By.XPath("//button//span"), gecisScreen))
{
     if (item.Text.In("Yükle"))
     {
          item.Tikla();
          break;
     }
}
```